# AngularUI Tooltips - use function to return tooltip value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip, ui.bootstrap

I am trying to use a function to return the value to render as a tooltip for Angular JS ui.bootstrap. I need to do this so I can get the correct tooltip in an ng-repeat loop. The tooltips work fine if I directly access the value in the html tooltip, such as `tooltip="{{tooltips.rules.start}}`, but not if I use the function `tooltipHelper` to return a value like `tooltip="tooltipHelper('rules', '{{fieldName}}')"`, that just sets the tooltip as the string `tooltipHelper('rules', 'start')` for example.

relevant code:

JS

```
$scope.tooltips = {
            rules: {
                name: '',
                weight: 'Sorts the rules, larger values sink to the bottom',
                active: 'Enable/disable rule',
                tag: 'Select a tag from the allowed tags list. To add tags to the allowed list go to the "tags" page',
                start: 'Click to set the start time',
                end: 'Click to set the end time',
                activate: 'Click to set the activate datetime',
                expire: 'Click to set the expire datetime'
            }
        };

$scope.tooltipHelper = function(type, name){
            return $scope.tooltips[type][name];
        };
```

HTML/Jade

```
div.required(ng-repeat="fieldName in datetime.fields", id="{{fieldName}}")
    input.form-control.datetime(type="text", value="{{fieldName}}, tooltip="tooltipHelper('rules', '{{fieldName}}')")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that @umarius's answer and a morning brain led me to the answer:

```
tooltip="{{tooltipHelper('rules', fieldName)}}"
```

I allow the variable to be passed without interpolation and it works fine and then interpolate after I get the return value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to apply the interpolation to the tooltipHelper function call, which will lead to double interpolate markup.

Solve the problem in one of these ways:

1. Inline the code of the function tooltipHelper:

```
    div.required(ng-repeat="fieldName in datetime.fields", id="{{fieldName}}")
        input.form-control.datetime(type="text", value="{{fieldName}}, tooltip="{{tooltips[type][name]}}")
```

2. Remove the inner interpolation of {{fieldname}} and change the tooltipHelper function to access fieldName from the scope:

```
    $scope.tooltipHelper = function(type){
        var name = $scope.fieldName;
        return $scope.tooltips[type][name];
    };

    div.required(ng-repeat="fieldName in datetime.fields", id="{{fieldName}}")
        input.form-control.datetime(type="text", value="{{fieldName}}, tooltip="{{tooltipHelper('rules')}}")
```

Comment: this makes no sense, how am I supposed to know which ng-repeat I am on if I don't pass the fieldName to the function?